# Puedo poner el foco en una fila de mi gridview segun el codigo?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim sql As String = "SELECT IdProd, Nombre, Precio FROM RE_ProdServ WHERE Codigo =" & lblCodProd.Text
dt = SMT_AbrirTabla(Conexion, sql)
Dim id As Integer
id = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows.Item(0).Item(0))

  If id = Convert.ToInt16(SelProductos.VistaProdSeleccionados.GetRowCellValue(i, "IdProd")) Then

  'Aqui seria donde pone el foco'

  End If
```

Comment: ¿Porqué no lo intentas?, y si no te funciona, colocas una pregunta indicando el error que te sale. Debes colocar una pregunta acerca de un error específico.

Comment: Soy nuevo en stack, te pregunto, me estas diciendo que siempre debo hacer preguntas acerca de un error en especifico? o que procure hacerlas asi.

Comment: Sí, además lo decía también por el titulo de la pregunta, creo que debería cambiar. Con esto no quiero decir que solo se deben presentar errores, si no que tu pregunta va más por si funciona un código o no, por que también hay preguntas conceptuales o de performance que son perfectamente válidas acá.

Answer (score 2):

La fila puedes establecerla con la propiedad FocusedRowHandle y la columna con la propiedad FocusedColumn.
Luego no tienes más que llamar al método ShowEditor() para iniciar la edición de la celda.

```
SelProductos.VistaProdSeleccionados.FocusedRowHandle = i
SelProductos.VistaProdSeleccionados.FocusedColumn = SelProductos.VistaProdSeleccionados.Columns("IdProd")
SelProductos.VistaProdSeleccionados.ShowEditor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias implementar con la ayuda de linq

```
Dim row As DataGridViewRow = VistaProdSeleccionados.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells("IdProd").Value) == id)

If row IsNot Nothing Then
   row.Selected = true
End If
```

de esta forma buscas en la columna IdProd y si alguna coincide con el id lo seleccionara